# How do I modify the New Post form in WordPress from a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am going to explain what I am creating so you can easily understand my problem.  I am making a plugin that let's you add a Restaurant Menu to your website.  I currently have custom admin dashboard menu links that take you to the new post page if you want to add a dish to the restaurant menu.  I want to modify the "new post" page so that there is a price field and a thumbnail uploader as well as to change the title of the page from "Add New Page" to "Add New Dish".  I have created a custom post type of "dish" and I only want these changes to occur when the post type is dish.  How can I add changes to the "Add New Page" form when the post type is dish?  Here is my plugin code so far... (P.S.) this is my first plugin!

```
<?php
/* 
Plugin Name: HeadChef
Plugin URI: http://google.com
Description:  Adds functionality for the restaurant's menu
Author: John Smith
Version: Alpha
Author URI: http://google.com
*/

add_action('admin_menu', 'hc_add_menu_items');
function hc_add_menu_items() {
  // $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $callback_function
  add_posts_page(__('Restaurant Menu'), __('My Menus'), 'read', 'edit.php?post_type=dish');
}

add_action( 'init', 'hc_create_post_type' );
function hc_create_post_type(){

    register_post_type( 'dish',
        array(
          'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Menu Dish' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Dish' )
          ),
          'public' => true,
          'has_archive' => true,
        )
      );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the labels in the UI, see the arguments of [`register_post_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments), some examples:

```
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Menu dish' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Dish' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add new dish' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New dish' ),
    // ...
);
```

You can add content to the edit page with [`add_meta_box()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box):

```
function myplugin_add_meta_box() {

    // add here which for post types you want this box
    $screens = array( 'dish' );

    add_meta_box(
        'myplugin_sectionid',
        __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'myplugin_meta_box_callback',
        $screens
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box' );
```